# Shared data and multi-threading in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, storage

I would like to add a [SyncAdapter](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html) to my app to update server-side data with minimal battery-use. For this, I need to have my application's main activity write data to some shared storage location that the SyncAdapter can then read in the [onPerformSync(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.html#onPerformSync(android.accounts.Account,%20android.os.Bundle,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentProviderClient,%20android.content.SyncResult)) method.

I'm trying to figure out where best to store this data and have the following questions:

- Could the SyncAdapter ever be called in a background thread while my main activity is executing in the foreground thread? I.e. do I need to worry about thread-safety of my storage access between the SyncAdapter and my main activity?
- Are there ever any situations in which two instances of my main activity could be in the ["Created"](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html) state? I.e. do I need to worry about thread-safety between two instances of my main activity?

Assuming that I do have to worry about any sort of thread safety, I have the following questions about [the different data storage options](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html):

- [Files in internal storage](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html):

  - Are there any atomic operations I can perform on files in internal storage?
  - How about file locks?
- [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html):

  - If two [editors](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html) in different threads simultaneously modify **different!!!** keys in the Shared-Preferences, could two simultaneous commits lead to the loss of one of the changes?
- [SQL database](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html):

  - Is the Android SQL Lite framework thread-safe if I simultaneously open the same SQL Lite database file from different threads?
- Are there other ways to share data among SyncAdapters and (multiple instances of (if that is even possible)) the main activity?

*Aside: To maximize compatibility of my app, I would like to not use any APIs greater than level 5.*

Answer (score 1):

I *think*, it should be possible to fix this issue by using a [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html).

ContentProviders don't inherently solve the multithreading issue, as stated in the documentation:

> Data access methods (such as [insert(Uri, ContentValues)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html#insert(android.net.Uri,%20android.content.ContentValues)) and [update(Uri, ContentValues, String, String[])](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html#update(android.net.Uri,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]))) may be called from many threads at once, and must be thread-safe. Other methods (such as [onCreate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html#onCreate())) are only called from the application main thread, and must avoid performing lengthy operations. See the method descriptions for their expected thread behavior.

But, unless the ContentProvider is declared with [`android:multiprocess=true`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html#multi), there *should* only ever be a single instance of the ContentProvider (if I understand this correctly), or at least all instances will live in the same process, i.e. they *should* have access the same **static** fields in the class definition.

With this, it *should* be possible to use the [standard Java synchronization features](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140767.html) to manage access to the storage-backed resources.

Please comment if I'm missing something...

*Aside: Why all the "should's"?

Because, unfortunately, with Android's documentation, I'm never 100% sure that it's reliable or complete. Example here: The quote above states that "[o]ther methods (such as onCreate()) are only called from the application main thread"... What happens when I set `android:multiprocess=true`? The docs there state that "if this flag is set to 'true', the system can create an instance in every process where there's a client that wants to interact with it". Would this lead to a call to onCreate() from a thread other than this application's main thread? Probably...*